# Changes in user_mailer.rb not taking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, actionmailer

I am making changes in my user_mailer.rb file, but I cannot get the updates to take. I have restarted my server after each change, but the error I am getting is still showing an old path method in my code that no longer exists. When I search the code for the old path method I cannot find it anywhere, but the error that is returned still shows the old path method causing the error.

Here is the new code in user_mailer.rb...

```
def invite_email(user, site_url)
  @user = user
  @url  = "#{site_url}#{new_user_password_path}?invite_code=#{@user.user_invite.code}"
  mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "#{@user.get_schools.map(&:name).join(', ')} - Welcome!", :from => "customersupport@app.com")
end
```

This generates a URL for the user to click from their email directing them to a page where they can set a password for their account (new_user_password_path). The old path was "new_password_path", and this is the path that is giving me an error. It is nowhere in the code and it is no longer a route, but I am still getting an error that says:

```
undefined local variable or method `new_password_path' for #<UserMailer:0x007fcbbcd19b58>
```

Comment: Make sure you are running correct application.

Comment: I am running the right application. And to clarify, I have restarted the server after each update...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to restarting your Delayed Job, because the save old version ruby code

Comment: I did need to restart delayed job. Thanks!